# Equirectangular Positioning Offset

Tags: dictionary, 3d, three.js, geopositioning

I'm building a simple 3D map using three.js that needs to have a few city positions plotted on it.

You can see my progress so far http://e.harrynorthover.com/map/, mouse over the pins to see what city it is suppose to be.

I'm using the Equirectangular projection method, but the issue I'm having is that I cannot seem to get it to position the cities correctly.

My code for the projection is:

```
RunGenerator.Utils.prototype.equirectangularPosition = function(lat, lng)
{
    var newX = ((lng + 180) * (RunGenerator.Utils.MAP_WIDTH  / 360));
    var newY = (((lat * -1) + 90) * (RunGenerator.Utils.MAP_HEIGHT  / 180));

    return {
        x:newX,
        y:newY
    };
}
```

And my code for creating the 3D map is:

```
RunGenerator.prototype.createMap = function()
{
    var that = this;

    var mapGeometry,
        mapTexture,
        mapMaterial,
        mapMaterial2,
        mapTexture2,
        mat;

    mapGeometry             = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1024, 794, 10, 10 );
    mat                     = new THREE.Matrix4();

    mapMaterial             = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map:this.mapTexture[0], transparent: true, color:0xFFFFFF } );
    mapMaterial2            = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map:this.mapTexture[1], transparent: true, color:0xFFFFFF, wireframe:false, opacity:.5 } );

    this.map                = new THREE.Mesh( mapGeometry, mapMaterial );
    var map2                = new THREE.Mesh( mapGeometry, mapMaterial2 );

    map2.position.z         = -5;

    //this.map.position.x     = -30;
    //this.map.position.y     = 80;
    this.map.position.z     = 0;

    this.map.scale.x        = this.map.scale.y = this.map.scale.z = 1;

    //mat.makeTranslation( 0, 100, 0 );
    //mapGeometry.applyMatrix( mat );

    //this.map.rotation.z     = 90;

    this.map.add(map2);
    this.scene.add(this.map);
};
```

My data:

```
{
    name: 'Southampton',
    waypoint: {
        latitude: '50.9039500',
        longitude: '-1.4042800'
    }
},
{
    name: 'LA',
    waypoint: {
        latitude: '34.0522300',
        longitude: '-118.2436800'
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss as to why the projection isnt working. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I had to solve this same problem.

Here's the code I ended up doing. It's in AS3 but should be easy to port:

```
private function getMercatorPoint(lat : Number, lon : Number, mapwidth : uint, mapheight : uint) : Point
{
    return new Point(((lon+180) / 360) * mapwidth, ((90-GudermannianInv(lat)) / 180) * mapheight);
}

private function GudermannianInv(lat : Number) : Number
{
    var sign : Number = Math.sin(lat) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    var sin : Number = Math.sin(lat * 0.0174532925 * sign);
    return sign * (Math.log((1 + sin) / (1 - sin)) / 2) * 28.6478898;
}
```

You can find more details [here](http://ricardocabello.com/blog/post/681).

Comment: Thanks for the response! The other problem was that my map texture was slightly the wrong size and missing some parts to fit in with the mercator projection.